# API Platform : No resource found for object of type "AppBundle\Document\article"

Tags: mongodb, api, symfony, doctrine-orm, api-platform.com

i'm using symfony2 API platform to generate an api from my mongodb database but i get this error : 
**hydra:description: "No resource found for object of type "AppBundle\Document\article"",**

i have two mongo db documents user and article and each user has multiple articles so i'm trying to list all the users with all their articles titles so i can get something like this :

```
{
@id: "/user/53edb6200cf2400d584c2617",
@type: "user",
class: "de.freelancer.mongo.domain.User",
email: "feer@de.com",
displayname: "feer",
withnewsletter: false,
language: "de_DE",
active: true,
admin: false,
articles : ['article1','article2','article3']
}
```

here is my code :

**user Document**

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Document;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;
use Dunglas\ApiBundle\Annotation\Iri;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
@MongoDB\Document
@MongoDB\Document(collection="user")
/
class User{

    /*
    @MongoDB\Id(strategy="AUTO") */ 
    private $id;
    /**

    @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="articles", mappedBy="user") */
    private $articles;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->articles = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
    */
    public function getArticles()
    {
        return $this->articles;
    }
}
```

**articles document**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Document;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;
use Dunglas\ApiBundle\Annotation\Iri;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**

@MongoDB\Document
@MongoDB\Document(collection="article")
/
class article
{
    /*
    @MongoDB\Id(strategy="AUTO") */ 
    private $id;

    /**
    @MongoDB\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="user", inversedBy="articles") */
     private $user;

    /**
     */ 
    public function setUser(userProfile $user) 
    { 
        $this->user = $user;
        return $this; 
     }

    /**
     */ 
    public function getUser() {
        return $this->user; 
    }
}
```

can any one help me to get the list of the user articles

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Every class managed by API Platform needs to be marked with the `@ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource` annotation (or the equivalent in YAML or XML).

And there is no native MongoDB support yet (but this is [a work in progress](https://github.com/api-platform/core/pull/1248)).

You can still add MongoDB support by yourself using a custom [data provider](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/data-providers), but if you're a newcomer to API Platform, you should try to use Doctrine ORM and follow the official tutorial first: https://api-platform.com/docs/distribution/